# Update TextView dynamically

Tags: android

I want to update TextView in a listview in real time .I have a socket connection in which I am listening to json messages and I would like to parse/identify the json to update one of 5 TextViews within the existing list.

```
responseid=object.getString("ResponseID");
    if(responseid!=null){
        for(int j=0;j<myList.size();j++){
            //If value match then I want to update the textView of that particular row
            if(myList.get(j).getName().equals(cid)) { 
                   //I successfully get the value of Textview of particular row of Listview now I want to update the this Textview with item variable below.
                String item = (String) myAdapter.getItem(j).getName();
                //Here i want to update Textview
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }    
    }
```

Comment: So what happens if you run that code? It doesn't update? Do you get any king of errors in logcat?

Comment: Exactly, what do you need?

Comment: Are your items an object type you defined?

Comment: i want to update content of the TextView of particular row...

Comment: String item = (String) myAdapter.getItem(j).getName(); this giveme a Textview existing value now i wan to update this vale

Comment: first you used myList and then myAdapter...  to get the TextView use myList

Comment: String oldcount = countryList.get(j).getCount();
                          int oldcountint = Integer.parseInt(oldcount);
                          int newcount = oldcountint + 1;                                                                                            
                          countryList.get(j).setCount(Integer.toString(newcount));                          
                       dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
responseid=object.getString("ResponseID");
    if(responseid!=null){
        for(int j=0;j<myList.size();j++){
            if(myList.get(j).getName().equals(cid)) { 
                String item = (String) myAdapter.getItem(j).getName();
                ((TextView)myList.get(j)).setText(item);
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }    
    }
```

Comment: myList isrefernce of ArrayList<Cou> myList = new ArrayList<Cou>(); ithink this is not a listview so i cant use myList.get(j)).setText(item);

Comment: We may need more information to help you then... you haven't given us much to go on

Comment: String oldcount = countryList.get(j).getCount();
                          int oldcountint = Integer.parseInt(oldcount);
                          int newcount = oldcountint + 1;                                                                                            
                          countryList.get(j).setCount(Integer.toString(newcount));                          
                       dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

By calling `String item = (String) myAdapter.getItem(j).getName();` you just get the items name value.

To set the value cast the getItem to the defined class:

```
YourObjectType item = (YourObjectType)myAdapter.getItem(j);
item.setName("updatestring");
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: TextView tv = (TextView)dataAdapter.getItem(j).
                        tv.setText(fffbfbg);somthing like this is not working

Comment: what is type of your myAdapter?

Comment: private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Topics>

Comment: Then you will need to cast to Topics.

Write Topics where i wrote YourObjectType